# how to load a image to ImageView src using piccaso android studio

Tags: java, android

i am loading an image from firebase storage using Picasso

```
Picasso.get().load(obj.P_URI).into(profile);
```

[image lost its out line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9iOs.jpg)

it seem that it loaded into background i want it to load into src how can i do this XML below

```
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView_profile_id"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_45sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_45sdp"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="360dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/home_name_id"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/home_HorizontalScrollView_id"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/home_profile_id"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_43sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_43sdp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_circle"
        android:clipToOutline="true"
        android:outlineProvider="background"

        />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

[i want image load like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjslP.png)

Comment: Well, it works for me if picture is in png format. What's the format you use? Could you provide an actual obj.P_URI?

Comment: obj.pURI = is a image URL From FirebaseStorage in String format and  i am using a . jpg format

Comment: is  working for me also the problem is when i add image . it adding into ImageView  background so android:background="@drawable/bg_circle"  get replaced and image edge is showing  bg_circle is a drawable resource      <corners android:radius="@dimen/_360sdp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/black"/>
    <corners android:radius="360dp"/>

Comment: Well, it can't load it into background. If "image lost its out line" is what you get it means something is wrong with the picture or the code. It looks distorted. Anyway, you have CardView with radius which already should clip the picture

Comment: Maybe issue is that you put it `into(profile)` instead of `into(homeProfileId)`?

Answer (score 0):

i just wanted the outline for circle profile and same time want to load image from the url it seem that Picasso can not load image into scr . changing xml to this way fixed my problem .  hope this will help someone

XML

```
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView_profile_id"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_65sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_65sdp"
    android:backgroundTint="#51CDC9"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="360dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/singup_profile_id"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_63sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_63sdp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/default_profile_icon"
        android:clickable="true"

        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profileRing_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_circle_edge" />


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

in drawable  bg_circle_edge

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<stroke android:width="@dimen/_2sdp"/>
<stroke android:color="@color/white"/>
<corners android:radius="@dimen/_360sdp"/>
<corners android:radius="360dp"/>

</shape>
```